# Carry a boxed iPhone 6 to the USA - do I need to declare it to customs?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, europe, electronic-items

I have a gift for a friend from the father, a new boxed iPhone 6 and I am travelling to USA. Can I bring it with me? Do I have to declare it and maybe pay custom duties?

Which is the right way to carry with me? Maybe I can put it in the hold luggage? What are the risks? Can they seize it?

I am an American citizen, I am not resident i am visitor, I am travelling back to work.

Comment: Are you asking for advice on how to avoid paying custom duties?

Comment: Of course you have to declare it.

Comment: @JoErNanO No, I'd like to know which is the right way to carry it with me, if I have to declare it and if there are duties to pay at the Arrivals. By risks I mean if they can seizure it.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany ok so, at my arrive I have to declare it in NY.

Comment: Ok then please add this information in the question body. ;)

Comment: If you are not resident then you are a visitor! It's binary.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany sorry corrected

Comment: *"If you are not resident then you are a visitor! It's binary."* Well, kind of... It's actually more complicated. For USCIS you're a resident only when you got green card. So even if you're living in US on H1B or similar, you're still "a visitor". Yet the state you live in would consider you a resident.

Also, I'm not sure if US citizen will ever be considered a visitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, always declare. If you get caught with it and you don't declare it, you'll be marked as a "smuggler" and that will stay on your file for years. Every time you travel, they'll see that and you'll be more likely to be stopped. It happened to a few people I know. Also, if you want to apply for Nexus or Global Entry, you'll probably be denied.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you have to declare it. Here is the form. There is no ambiguity ("including gifts for someone else" or "will remain in the U.S." covers either situation of you being resident or not).

[image]

I'm not a customs broker (so E&OE), but the harmonized tariff code for iPhones appears to be 8517.12.0050, which would appear to be free of duty. Your friend may be liable to pay use tax to his U.S. state of residence, but individuals often fail to do that, unless it's for business use.

Comment: Please please please add a nicer screenshot. :)

Comment: @JoErNanO Got that from CBP website but I'm sure i can do better.

Comment: Ok so, appear to be free of duty. The phone will be for personal use.

Comment: @GiovanniBastianelli It's hard to claim personal use if you bring a sealed, boxed gift.

Comment: @JoErNanO well I don't really want to claim personal use because it is a gift I can't unbox it. I have my own cellphone so I would travel with two phones, one without plan..

Comment: @GiovanniBastianelli Just declare fully and answer any questions truthfully.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany yes thank you I will do it that way so.